# 「過去に起きたことを」今、経験として、「持っている」という形になるのです

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from my conversation via e-mail with my language partner. For some context:

> アンドレアスさんが言っているのは、「経験・経歴を表すテイル形」のことだと思います。これは中上級向け文法書に出ている使い方で、少し難しいです。
> まず、現在進行形の文と区別するために、必ず過去を表す言葉と一緒に使います。
>
> 「過去に起きたことを」今、経験として、「持っている」という形になるのです。

The sentence in question:

> 「過去に起きたことを」今、経験として、「持っている」という形になるのです。

My attempt at translation:

> Treating something that happened in the past as present, it becomes a form meaning 'it (still) lasts'.

The main issue are those quotation marks and the interaction with the environment. I don't really know whether I understood the part 「過去に起きたことを」今、経験として correctly. I also don't know whether the way I interpreted 「持っている」
という形 correctly. I think what she wants to tell me is that when I use ている for events which happened in the past, these events must live on in the present? Is that it?

Comment: めっちゃ説明うまそうな人やな。SEに来てくれへんかな。

Comment: I don't come up with good explanation but the translation will be "(It) will be a form in which you currently have what happened in the past as an experience".

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how best to express it, but it feels like you're misunderstanding two key phrases in the sentence.

1. 経験として

I don't even see where this appears in your translation, but it means "as an experience."

2. 持っている

I think you're translating this as "still lasts" but I think here it means "something one has/possesses"

As I'm sure you're aware from the part above, your interlocutor is explaining a grammatical form in Japanese, specifically a usage of 〜ている.

For the whole thing,

> 「過去に起きたことを」今、経験として、「持っている」 という形になるのです。

My translation would be:

> This a form that expresses that "something which happened in the past"  is now "being possessed/held" as an experience.

I think the parts in quotes serve a two-fold purpose. First, they indicate the person explaining is using the same sort of construction they are explaining (I think?) Second, they express that these are not proper terms for linguistics or Japanese grammar but rather colloquial quotations. (I could be completely wrong on the quote usage).

Comment: 経験として  shall be represented by "Treating...as present". Is that a legit interpretation?^^

Comment: I don't think so..."treating as present" = いると認める or 現在的と認める。

Answer (score -1):

The explanation 「過去に起きたことを」今経験として「持っている」 doesn't seem an appropriate Japanese sentence. It's rather purported to explain ている-form by comparing with English perfect-form "have done". The origin of "have done something" is "have something done". This historical formation of perfect sentence is often explained "have the result of something done in past time still in present time". The meaning of the result developed into one's experience and so perfect sentence now means one's experience.
Though this explanation using "have" is surely easier to understand English, it's confusing for Japanese. But what is explained here is the same. If I explain ている-form by the origin of word formation, I say "The result of something done in past time still exists in present time". It's sure that existence sentence develops into possession sentence in Japanese, for example, 私には弟がいます "I have a brother", so your partner's explanation is not wrong but just confusing for you, I think.